# Retrieving ids gives unexpected result?

Tags: python, image, kivy, instance, kivymd

So I have a problem that I want to check that if an image exists inside a button and I have created a dictionary containing all the ids of the 16 images. I have a total of 64 buttons and only 16 contain images so I have created a function that checks if any of the ids in the dictionary are inside the button object `(instance.children)`.
The result that I am getting when I run the script is:
`__super__ object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Below is some of my .kv code:

```
Button:
    id: button_1
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (1,1,1,1)
    on_press: root.moves(self, root)

    AsyncImage:
        id: white_1
        source: 'imgs/WhiteCastle.png'
        center_x: self.parent.center_x
        center_y: self.parent.center_y

Button:
    id: button_2
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    on_press: root.moves(self, root)

    AsyncImage:
        id: white_2
        source: 'imgs/WhiteKnight.png'
        center_x: self.parent.center_x
        center_y: self.parent.center_y

Button:
    id: button_3
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (1,1,1,1)
    on_press: root.moves(self, root)

    AsyncImage:
        id: white_3
        source: 'imgs/WhiteBishop.png'
        center_x: self.parent.center_x
        center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

And now here is my .py code:

```
def img_list(self):
    img_ids_list = []

for x in range(1, 17):
    img_ids_list.append(f"white_{x}")

for y in range(1, 17):
    img_ids_list.append(f"black_{y}")

return img_ids_list

def moves(self, instance, root):
    all_ids = root.ids
    id_of_button = self.get_id(instance)
    img_id = self.check_if_img_exists(instance, root)

def check_if_img_exists(self, instance, root):
    img_ids = self.img_list()

    if img_ids[0] in root.ids:
        print("Ready for launch!")
        for x in range(1, 32):
            imag = img_ids[x]
            asyncImage = root.ids.imag
            if asyncImage in instance.children:
                print("Button contains an AsyncImage")
                return asyncImage

    print("Button does not contain an AsyncImage")

def get_id(self, instance):
    for id, widget in instance.parent.parent.ids.items():
        if widget.__self__ == instance:
            return id
```

Can someone plzz help.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: we can't see full error message, we can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind - so we can't help you. You have to put all details in question (not in comments) or even better if you create minimal working code with your problem - and then we can copy and test it.